# How to keep connection alive in GO's websocket

Tags: websocket, go

I use `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket` in server, so client can get notification from server.

however, It seems after client connected to server, if there is no any data tranfer between client and server, server will return EOF error at `websocket.JSON.Receive()`, it looks like a timeout mechanism.

And I have search in Google, it seems websocket protocol has a **ping-pong** heartbeat to maintain the connection, I want to ask whether `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket` support this ping protocol or not?
What should I do if I want keep connection between client and server alive?

Comment: post your go code for websocket handler please. Probably you just need to add a `for` cycle to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As recently as 2013, the go.net websocket library [does not support (automatic) keep-alive messages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/NKfqwshOZHA).  You have two options:

- Implement an "application level" keep-alive by periodically having your application send a message down the pipe (either direction should work), that is ignored by the other side.
- Move to a different websocket library that does support keep-alives ([like this one](http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/go-websocket/websocket)) **Edit:** it looks like that library has been superseded by [Gorilla websockets](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket).

Comment: If implement by self, what is the time span about keep-alive?

Comment: That's probably worth a new SO question.

Answer (score 14):

Here's working drop-in solution for **gorilla/websocket** package.

```
func keepAlive(c *websocket.Conn, timeout time.Duration) {
    lastResponse := time.Now()
    c.SetPongHandler(func(msg string) error {
       lastResponse = time.Now()
       return nil
   })

   go func() {
     for {
        err := c.WriteMessage(websocket.PingMessage, []byte("keepalive"))
        if err != nil {
            return 
        }   
        time.Sleep(timeout/2)
        if(time.Since(lastResponse) > timeout) {
            c.Close()
            return
        }
    }
  }()
}
```

Comment: Where would this method 'keepAlive' be called from?