# What is proper time span for GO websocket to keep-alive

Tags: websocket, go

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646910/how-to-keep-connection-alive-in-gos-websocket/23663282?noredirect=1#comment36379911_23663282), In `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket`, it needs to implement keep-alive by self.

So what is proper time span that web-socket to keep alive? Thanks!

Comment: One option, while not an answer to the question, is use the [`github.com/gorilla/websocket`](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket) package instead. It supports PING/PONG + some extra stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally keeping the keep-alive just under 60 seconds is good idea. (Heroku for instance requires you to send some data at least every 55 seconds) So sending a ping/pong every 50 seconds should keep your connection alive. Do note that you might have to choose a shorter interval depending on your server stack, any web accelerators, proxies and caches. A NAT router also influences the interval. Most of the time 50 seconds will work but 25 seconds usually does the trick when 50 doesn't.