# Send messages from kafka into websocket

Tags: go, apache-kafka, websocket

I created a web service with gin-framework in golang. In this project I also consume some kafka messages that comes from a particular topic. What I'm trying to achive is to pour out the messages that I receive from the topic into the websocket. So the communication is only one way and more than 1 person can connect to the web socket and see the messages coming in.
I tought to use channel, so inside the function that receives the kafka message I have something like this:

```
ch <- KafkaMessage
```

While in gin framework I create something like this:

```
requestRouterRPCv1.GET("wf-live", wsWorkFlowLive)

func wsWorkFlowLive(c *gin.Context) {
    ws, err := upGrader.Upgrade(c.Writer, c.Request, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error get connection")
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer ws.Close()

    err = ws.WriteJSON(<-ch)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error write message: " + err.Error())
    }
}

var upGrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    CheckOrigin: func(r *http.Request) bool {
        return true
    },
}
```

Here the html snipped that I use to test the websocket:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
     <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8" />
       <title>index</title>
    </head>
     <body>
       <h1>test websocket</h1>
       <p id="message-json"></p>
      <p id="message-text"></p>
            <script>
        function jsonWS() {
          var ws = new WebSocket("ws://ws.acme.com/ws/v1/wf-live");

          ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            console.log("Received Message: " + evt.data);
            document.getElementById("message-json").innerText += evt.data;
          };

          ws.onclose = function (evt) {
            console.log("Connection closed.");
          };
        }

        // Start websocket
        jsonWS();
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

But I miss something, I'm quite a newbie, becasue I have the following wrong behaviours once I recevie the first kafka message:

1. Only the first message is shown, after that connection is quickly closed
2. To see the second ones I have to refresh the page, and this is not the websocket way
3. Because the connection is closed the channel it not red, so it's stuck in the cosume function until I read it. I cannot have this behaviour
4. to avoid the point 3, I think I have to have a mechanism where I send the message to the channel only when one or more ws is connected.

Comment: 1. you are closing connection your self with defer statement

Comment: 2. you are not looping keep receiving messages from ch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat#chat-example) is close to what you need. The example broadcasts messages received from any client to all connected clients. Do the following to adapt the code to your use case:

- Change the [client read pump](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/69d0eb9187b6dead8fe84b2423518475e5cc535c/examples/chat/client.go#L56) to discard received messages instead of sending messages to the hub.

  ```
  func (c *Client) readPump() {
      defer func() {
          c.hub.unregister <- c
          c.conn.Close()
      }()
      c.conn.SetReadLimit(maxMessageSize)
      c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait))
      c.conn.SetPongHandler(func(string) error { 
      c.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(pongWait)); return nil })
      for {
          if _, _, err := c.NextReader(); err != nil {
            break
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Change your Kafka read loop to send messages to the [Hub.broadcast](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/69d0eb9187b6dead8fe84b2423518475e5cc535c/examples/chat/hub.go#L14) channel.

  ```
  for {
      msg, err := c.ReadMessage(xxx)
      if err != nil {
            // handle error
      }
      hub.broadcast <- msg
  }
  ```
- Delete [the code that coalesces messages in the client send queue to a single websocket message](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/blob/69d0eb9187b6dead8fe84b2423518475e5cc535c/examples/chat/client.go#L104-L109) or adjust the client to handle multiple Kafka messages in a single websocket message.

Answer (score 1):

You are close. Just missing two things.

1- Using *select* statement to keep receiving new messages from the kafka channels.

2- Maintain an active websocket connecting. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23663282/5061033) have a bit more details

Let me know whether this works out for you.